# is not contract address during truffle test

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

I have a stupid smart contract like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract ProdottoFactory  {

    function foo() view returns(string nome){
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

And I want to test it with chai

```
var Prodotto = artifacts.require("ProdottoFactory");
expect = require("chai").expect;


contract("descrizione primo test", function () {
    describe("test 2", function () {
        it("blablabla", function () {
            return Prodotto.new().then(
                istance => {
                    prodottoContract = istance;
                }
            )
        })
    })
})


contract("descrizione primo test2", function () {
    describe("test 2 2", function () {
        it("blablabla2",function () {
            return prodottoContract.foo().then(function (res) {
                expect(res.toString()).to.be.equal("foo")
            })
        })
    })
})
```

When I run the command
truffle test
I have this error

> Error: Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address 0xe8f29e5c4ca41c5b40ed989439ddeae4d9384984 is not a contract address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*truffle.js*

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545, // Ganache GUI
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

*contracts/ProdottoFactory.sol*

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract ProdottoFactory  {
  function foo() pure public returns(string nome){
    return "foo";
  }
}
```

*test/ProdottoFactory.js*

```
var pf = artifacts.require("ProdottoFactory");

contract('ProdottoFactory', function(accounts) {
  var pfInstance;

  before(function() {
    return pf.new()
      .then(function(instance) {
        pfInstance = instance;
      });
  });

  it("should return foo", function() {
    return pfInstance.foo.call()
      .then(function(str) {
        assert.equal(str, "foo");
      });
  });
});
```

I made 2 small changes in your contract:

1. I added `public` keyword. It's good practice to always define the visibility of your function.
2. I replaced `view` to `pure`. When you are not reading from blockchain/state variable, use `pure`. More info can be found inside the docs [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#pure-functions).

FYI, you don't have to require chai or mocha library. It's already there when you init a Truffle project using `truffle init` command. The `before` keyword is part of Mocha library. You can read more about it [here](https://mochajs.org/#hooks).

Lastly, if you want to know the differences between `new` and `deployed` keyword in Truffle, read my thread [here](https://twitter.com/zulhhandyplast/status/1026181801239171072).

Comment: Just in case you want to look at the Truffle project I created for this answer, go to here https://gitlab.com/zulhfreelancer/prodotto-factory